# WPF Master-Detail Data Entry Reusable Control

Tags: wpf, crud, master-detail

I am looking for some base window or user control class to create a master-detail data entry (eg. Invoice) form in WPF without writing code for CRUD operations which will have Add,Edit,Save,Revert,Delete Buttons.

We have hundreds of Master (eg. Customer) or Master-Detail (eg. Invoice) like forms in our project. so to avoid repetitive codes I want a reusable control in which I just need to specify master table name, id field name, detail table names. the control will do all the CRUD operations without writing any extra code for those.

Any advice is much appreciated!